# Symfony access control with FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to make an authenticated section called /admin but putting in access_control has broken my API (nothing is returned). I don't need authentication for the API so I've used IS_ANONYMOUS as role. Here is my security.yml, what am I doing wrong?

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username        # fos_user.user_provider.username_email does not seem to work (OAuth-spec related ("username + password") ?)

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~

        oauth_token:                                   # Everyone can access the access token URL.
            pattern: ^/api/oauth/v2/token
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/api                             # All URLs are protected
            fos_oauth: true                            # OAuth2 protected resource
            stateless: true                            # Do no set session cookies
            anonymous: true                           # Anonymous access is not allowed
            security: false
    access_control:
        # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_ANONYMOUS }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you edit to tell us what specifically your problem and error message/expected result is?

Comment: Are your users loaded from a database? I do not see any users defined in for using in_memory. Might check out this section on loading users: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#configure-security-to-load-from-your-entity

Comment: try with
    IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
instead of your 'role'